# using System.Diagnostics is available in xamarin or not

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

i want to write event in xamarin project.i could not able to access the Eventsource constructor. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource/)

```
public class EventSource : IDisposable
```

Provides the ability to create events for event tracing for Windows (ETW).

Comment: cant able to access the reference

Comment: You can't add mscorlib?

Comment: i tried to add but it says mscorlib.dll will be added default. you cant able to add now.